# Examining second derivatives.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

If I have a set of continuous functions X on an interval [a,b], such that f(a)=f(b)=0 for all functions in the set. Is it possible to create a mapping from X to C[a,b] by using the second derivative function?

In other words, would the second derivative of every element in X comprise every continuous function on the interval [a,b]?

Comment: what about non-differentiable functions therein?

Comment: Sorry, lets assume that both first and second derivatives exist for all elements of X.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your question: Let $X = \{f\in C^2([a,b]):f(a)=f(b)=0\}$, i.e. the set of functions on $[a,b]$ whose second derivative exists and is continuous and is zero on the endpoints. Is the mapping from $X$ to $C([a,b])$ given by $f\mapsto f''$ surjective?

The answer is yes. Given any $g\in C([a,b])$, it has a second antiderivative $f$ such that $f'' = g$. We then just add an appropriate linear function $l$ such that $(f+l)(a) = (f+l)(b) = 0$, since linear functions have vanishing second derivatives.